# What are the secret achievements in Bloons td5 on android?

Tags: achievements, bloons-td-5

I'm trying to collect the all of the achievements. I just need to know what to do to get the secret achievements.

Answer (score 2):

If you are playing on Steam (I am not sure about the mobile version but they should be there too)

- All 3 Medals (Easy, Medium, and Hard) on Ice Flow.
- All 3 Medals (Easy, Medium, and Hard) on Challenger Deep.
- All 3 Medals (Easy, Medium, and Hard) on Ice Flow Co-Op.
- All 3 Medals (Easy, Medium, and Hard) on Challenger Deep Co-Op.